# Get index value of array

Tags: arrays, indexing, coffeescript, framerjs

Trying to do something simple but hitting a brick wall. I'm trying to get the index value of an item in an array, I'm using Coffeescript not plain Javascript.

Code:

```
for i in ["The Royal Family", "Residences", "History & Tradition", "News", "Events", "Jobs"]
    createSubMenuLayer(i, i.value)
```

I've tried i.index, i.value, plain old i (which gives me the string). I want to get the index value to position items based upon the position in the array.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `for x in ...` form of the `for` loop iterates over the values of an array, not the indexes. But [the documentation](http://coffeescript.org/#loops) says:

```
# Fine five course dining.
courses = ['greens', 'caviar', 'truffles', 'roast', 'cake']
menu i + 1, dish for dish, i in courses
# -------------------^^^^^^^
```

So you're looking for this:

```
for e, i in [...]
    createSubMenuLayer(i, e)
```